# Remove duplicate values from a CSV in Sequelize and Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, sequelize.js

I am trying to read in a csv file and remove the duplicate values when they are created. I tried using an Async to do it but, no luck. I have reverted back to a simpler way and doesn't remove the duplicates. The code below reads and creates the object but, doesn't remove duplicates. I have used the fast-csv library to read a csv in.

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const Staff = require('../models/Staff');
const fs = require('fs');
const csv = require('fast-csv');

module.exports = router;

router.get('/add_csv', function (req, res) {
   var stream = fs.createReadStream("./public/assets/csv/data_extract.csv");
   csv
   .fromStream(stream, {headers : true})
   .on("data", function(data){
       console.log(data);

        const userName = data.name;
        const firstName = data.forename;
        const lastName = data.surname;
        const email = data.college_email;

        Staff.findOrCreate({
            where : {
                userName : userName,
                firstName : firstName,
                lastName : lastName,
                email : email
            } 
        });
   })
   .on("end", function(){
       console.log("done");
       res.send("done");
   });
});
```

Comment: would seem we need to see whats happening in FindOrCreate()

Comment: @bcperth what do you mean? The output?

Comment: Ignore that first remark. Have you tried .spread as below

Comment: do you really need to use sequelize to remove duplicate?

Comment: @RahulSharma how could I delete them programmatically then?

Comment: is all duplicate rows are identical?

Comment: @RahulSharma There are rows with the same values

Comment: I have posted my answer. I have tested that with my sample data

Comment: Can you please verify and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the .spread clause for debugging?

If you add the .spread clause it will tell you what it is doing record by record.

change

```
    Staff.findOrCreate({
        where : {
            userName : userName,
            firstName : firstName,
            lastName : lastName,
            email : email
        } 
    });
```

to

```
    Staff.findOrCreate({
        where : {
            userName : userName,
            firstName : firstName,
            lastName : lastName,
            email : email
        } 
    })
    .spread((staff, created) => {
        console.log(staff.get({
        plain: true
    }))
    console.log(created);
```

This will print out the record and show true if new record was created or otherwise false. Hope my syntax is right..

see here for example code:
http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html

Comment: The problem is that I already have an output showing who is in the database and I can see duplicate values. I want to be able to skip any duplicate row if they already exist in the database.

Comment: Yes I understand. You can see exactly what is happening with FindOrCreate using spread. That is not working correctly right? So suggestion is just for debugging. Then proceed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this I have tested

```
sort -u data_extract.csv >> data_extract_unique.csv
```

It will write unique data to the data_extract_unique.csv

If you want to use this while reading csv do this using this

```
const reorder = require('csv-reorder');

reorder({
  input: './cashback.txt',
  output: './output.csv',
  sort: 'userName',
  type: 'string',
  remove: true,
  "remove-duplicates": true,
  metadata: false
})
.then(metadata => {
  console.log(metadata)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
});
```

I have tested this.

after successful removal, you can read data from output.csv

I used this csv as sample

** Input Csv **

userName, firstName, lastName, email

rahsai374, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

rahsai374, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

rahsai374, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

rahsai574, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

** Output Csv **

userName, firstName, lastName, email

rahsai374, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

rahsai574, Rahul, sharma, rsharma@gmail.com

Comment: Not sure if you understand what I am trying to do. I don't want to create a new csv. I want to remove duplicate usernames programmatically. So the user creating the csv don't have to do it

Comment: But what you were doing using findOrCreate is happens with a combination of all the userName and firstName, lastName and email

Comment: Yes please @RahulSharma

Comment: please check now

Comment: can I ask what sort : 'User' is?

Comment: I am super confused on where to put this. Can you please take the time to use some of the code I have provided. I will star your solution after. @RahulSharma

Comment: sort is column names on which you want to remove duplicates

Comment: I am getting Error: Column not found.

Comment: this error comes when you need to pass column name in sort on which you want to remove duplicates. can you post some sample data of your csv in question so that will help you out.

Comment: is ti possible to sort with more than one field ? like id and username

Answer (score -1):

Try to use another approach, when on 'data' is fired just add data to the array, on 'end' is fired get unique data from the array and insert them into DB.
It should event increase performance due to the fact that you will execute only one DB query instead of query per each row.

```
const _ = require('lodash');

module.exports = router;

router.get('/add_csv', function (req, res) {
   const dataToInsert = []; 
   var stream = fs.createReadStream("./public/assets/csv/data_extract.csv");
   csv
   .fromStream(stream, {headers : true})
   .on("data", (data) => {
       console.log(data);
       dataToInsert.push({
        userName : userName,
        firstName : firstName,
        lastName : lastName,
        email : email
    });
   })
   .on("finish", () => {
       console.log("done");
       const uniqueDataToInsert = _.uniqBy(dataToInsert, ['userName', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email'])
       Staff.bulkCreate(uniqueDataToInsert, {ignoreDuplicates: true}).then((result) => {
        res.send("done");
       }).catch((error) => {
           res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify(error));
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: This is only returning the first row in the csv though

Comment: and also if I keep going to that page. It will still insert an existing username

Comment: If you are using mysql , you can pass ignoreDuplicates: true to the bulkCreate method to have it ignore duplicate/unique constraints.

Comment: Im using postgresql and sequelize

Comment: I want to remove all duplicate usernames

Comment: can you remove all duplicates via SQL query and then try to use ignoreDuplicates: true for buldCreate?  I think it should work for PG as well.

Comment: While this might improve performance on account of only having one query at the end of the import, it could fail altogether if the data set you are importing is very large (or if each row contains a lot of data).

Because you are pushing everything into an array, your app may run out of memory before you have a chance to import.

Therefore I think for production apps it's better to import each row one by one as it's streamed from the CSV file.